# How to extract logs between two time stamps

Tags: text-processing, sed, awk, grep

I want to extract all logs between two timestamps. Some lines may not have the timestamp, but I want those lines also. In short, I want every line that falls under two time stamps. My log structure looks like:

```
[2014-04-07 23:59:58] CheckForCallAction [ERROR] Exception caught in +CheckForCallAction :: null
--Checking user--
Post
[2014-04-08 00:00:03] MobileAppRequestFilter [DEBUG] Action requested checkforcall
```

Suppose I want to extract everything between `2014-04-07 23:00` and `2014-04-08 02:00`.

*Please note the start time stamp or end time stamp may not be there in the log, but I want every line between these two time stamps.*

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7575267/extract-data-from-log-file-in-specified-range-of-time

Comment: Do you just need to do this just once or programmatically at various times?

Comment: Reason I ask is because you can do [two contextual grep's](https://dpaste.de/XcN8) (one to grab everything after the starting delimiter and another to stop printing at the ending delimiter) if you know the literal values. If the dates/times can change, tou can easily generate these on the fly by feeding user input through the `date -d` command and using that to construct the search pattern.

Comment: @Ramesh, the referenced question is too broad.

Comment: @JoelDavis : I want to do it programmatically. So everytime i just need to enter desired time stamp to extract the logs between those time stamp in my /tmp location.

Comment: @Ramesh : it's too broad so i am seaking help else i would have done it by my own. Thanx for your suggestion and giving reference.

Answer (score 22):

You can use `awk` for this:

```
$ awk -F'[]]|[[]' \
  '$0 ~ /^\[/ && $2 >= "2014-04-07 23:00" { p=1 }
   $0 ~ /^\[/ && $2 >= "2014-04-08 02:00" { p=0 }
                                        p { print $0 }' log
```

Where:

- `-F` specifies the characters `[` and `]` as field separators using a regular expression
- `$0` references a complete line
- `$2` references the date field
- `p` is used as boolean variable that guards the actual printing
- `$0 ~ /regex/` is true if regex matches `$0`
- `>=` is used for lexicographically comparing string (equivalent to e.g. `strcmp()`)

### Variations

The above command line implements [right-open time interval](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interval_%28mathematics%29#Terminology) matching. To get closed interval semantics just increment your right date, e.g.:

```
$ awk -F'[]]|[[]' \
  '$0 ~ /^\[/ && $2 >= "2014-04-07 23:00"    { p=1 }
   $0 ~ /^\[/ && $2 >= "2014-04-08 02:00:01" { p=0 }
                                           p { print $0 }' log
```

In case you want to match timestamps in another format you have to modify the `$0 ~ /^\[/` sub-expression. Note that it used to ignore lines without any timestamps from print on/off logic.

For example for a timestamp format like `YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS` (without `[]` braces) you could modify the command like this:

```
$ awk \
  '$0 ~ /^[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2} [0-2][0-9]:[0-5][0-9]:[0-5][0-9]/
      {
        if ($1" "$2 >= "2014-04-07 23:00")     p=1;
        if ($1" "$2 >= "2014-04-08 02:00:01")  p=0;
      }
    p { print $0 }' log
```

(note that also the field separator is changed - to blank/non-blank transition, the default)

Comment: Although I don't think this is a string problem (see [my answer](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/124031/61786)), you could make yours much more readable, and probably a bit faster, by not repeating all of the tests: 
`$1 ~ /^[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}/ && $2 ~/[0-2][0-9]:[0-5][0-9]:[0-5][0-9]/ { Time = $1" "$2; if (Time >= "2014-04-07 23:00" ) { p=1 } if (Time >= "2014-04-08 02:00:01" ) { p=0 } }
 p`

Comment: Hi Max, One more small doubt.. If i have something like Apr-07-2014 10:51:17 . Then what changes i need to do.. I tried `code` $0 ~ /^[a-z|A-Z]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{4} [0-2][0-9]:[0-5][0-9]:[0-5][0-9]/ && $1" "$2 >= "Apr-07-2014 11:00" { p=1 } $0 ~ /^[a-z|A-Z]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{4} [0-2][0-9]:[0-5][0-9]:[0-5][0-9]/ && $1" "$2 >= "Apr-07-2014 12:00:01" { p=0 } `code` but its not working

Comment: @awk_FTW, changed the code such that the regex is explicitly shared.

Comment: @Amit, your original question did not indicate the wish to be able to parse arbitrary formatted timestamps. The above described method requires that the lexicographical ordering is the same as the date ordering. This is for `YYYY MM DD HH24 MI SS` or something similar the case - but not for something like `MM DD YYYY ....` or even `MMM DD YYYY`. You can always convert your timestamps on the fly into another format, though.

Answer (score 12):

Check out `dategrep` at https://github.com/mdom/dategrep

Description:

> dategrep searches the named input files for lines matching a date range and prints them to stdout.
>
> If dategrep works on a seekable file, it can do a binary search to find the first and last line to print pretty efficiently. dategrep can also read from stdin if one the filename arguments is just a hyphen, but in this case it has to parse every single line which will be slower.

Usage examples:

```
dategrep --start "12:00" --end "12:15" --format "%b %d %H:%M:%S" syslog
dategrep --end "12:15" --format "%b %d %H:%M:%S" syslog
dategrep --last-minutes 5 --format "%b %d %H:%M:%S" syslog
dategrep --last-minutes 5 --format rsyslog syslog
cat syslog | dategrep --end "12:15" -
```

Although this limitation may make this unsuitable for your exact question:

> At the moment dategrep will die as soon as it finds a line that is not parsable. In a future version this will be configurable.

Comment: I learned about this command only a couple days ago courtesy of http://onethingwell.org/post/81991115668/dategrep so, kudos to him!

Answer (score 3):

One alternative to `awk` or a non-standard tool is to use GNU `grep` for its contextual greps. GNU's `grep` will let you specify the number of lines after a positive match to print with `-A` and the preceding lines to print with `-B` For example:

```
[davisja5@xxxxxxlp01 ~]$ cat test.txt
Ignore this line, please.
This one too while you're at it...
[2014-04-07 23:59:58] CheckForCallAction [ERROR] Exception caught in +CheckForCallAction :: null
--Checking user--
Post
[2014-04-08 00:00:03] MobileAppRequestFilter [DEBUG] Action requested checkforcall
we don't
want these lines.


[davisja5@xxxxxxlp01 ~]$ egrep "^\[2014-04-07 23:59:58\]" test.txt -A 10000 | egrep "^\[2014-04-08 00:00:03\]" -B 10000
[2014-04-07 23:59:58] CheckForCallAction [ERROR] Exception caught in +CheckForCallAction :: null
--Checking user--
Post
[2014-04-08 00:00:03] MobileAppRequestFilter [DEBUG] Action requested checkforcall
```

The above essentially tells `grep` to print the 10,000 lines that follow the line that matches the pattern you're wanting to start at, effectively making your output start where you're wanting it to and go until the end (hopefully) whereas the second `egrep` in the pipeline tells it to only print the line with the ending delimiter and the 10,000 lines before it. The end result of these two is starting where you're wanting and not going passed where you told it to stop.

10,000 is just a number I came up with, feel free to change it to a million if you think your output is going to be too long.

Comment: How is this going to work if there is no log entry for the start and end ranges? If OP wants everything between 14:00 and 15:00, but there's no log entry for 14:00, then?

Comment: It will word about as well as the `sed` which is also searching for literal matches. `dategrep` is probably the most correct answer of all the ones given (since you need to be able to get "fuzzy" on what timestamps you'll accept) but like the answer says, I was just mentioning it as an alternative. That said, if the log is active enough to generate enough output to warrant cutting it's probably also going to have _some_ kind of entry for the given timeperiod.

Answer (score 1):

Well, it worked:

```
CMD=awk -v from=$Date1 -v to=$Date2
```

to count errors:

```
error_count=grep "error_message" ${logfile} | awk -F'[ .]' '{print $4}' | $CMD '$1>=from && $1<=to' | wc -l
```

here i used Date1 and Date2 as a parameter in which i stored the date at runtime.
`$4` gave me the timestamp in logs.

It was not taking date parameters directly in `awk` statement that's why i had to write CMD seperately (CMD is just kind of variable we can say)

Answer (score 0):

Using sed :

```
#!/bin/bash

E_BADARGS=23

if [ $# -ne "3" ]
then
  echo "Usage: `basename $0` \"<start_date>\" \"<end_date>\" file"
  echo "NOTE:Make sure to put dates in between double quotes"
  exit $E_BADARGS
fi 

isDatePresent(){
        #check if given date exists in file.
        local date=$1
        local file=$2
        grep -q "$date" "$file"
        return $?

}

convertToEpoch(){
    #converts to epoch time
    local _date=$1
    local epoch_date=`date --date="$_date" +%s`
    echo $epoch_date
}

convertFromEpoch(){
    #converts to date/time format from epoch
    local epoch_date=$1
    local _date=`date  --date="@$epoch_date" +"%F %T"`
    echo $_date

}

getDates(){
        # collects all dates at beginning of lines in a file, converts them to epoch and returns a sequence of numbers
        local file="$1"
        local state="$2"
        local i=0
        local date_array=( )
        if [[ "$state" -eq "S" ]];then
            datelist=`cat "$file" | sed -r -e "s/^\[([^\[]+)\].*/\1/" | egrep  "^[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2} [0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}"`
        elif [[ "$state" -eq "E" ]];then
            datelist=`tac "$file" | sed -r -e "s/^\[([^\[]+)\].*/\1/" | egrep  "^[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2} [0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}"`

        else
            echo "Something went wrong while getting dates..." 1>&2
            exit 500
        fi

        while read _date
            do
                epoch_date=`convertToEpoch "$_date"`
                date_array[$i]=$epoch_date
                #echo "$_date" "$epoch_date" 1>&2

            (( i++ ))
            done<<<"$datelist"
        echo ${date_array[@]}   


}

findneighbours(){
    # search next best date if date is not in the file using recursivity
    IFS="$old_IFS"
    local elt=$1
    shift
    local state="$1"
    shift
    local -a array=( "$@" ) 

    index_pivot=`expr ${#array[@]} / 2`
    echo "#array="${#array[@]} ";array="${array[@]} ";index_pivot="$index_pivot 1>&2
    if [ "$index_pivot" -eq 1 -a ${#array[@]} -eq 2 ];then

        if [ "$state" == "E" ];then
            echo ${array[0]}
        elif [ "$state" == "S" ];then
            echo ${array[(( ${#array[@]} - 1 ))]} 
        else
            echo "State" $state "undefined" 1>&2
            exit 100
        fi

    else
        echo "elt with index_pivot="$index_pivot":"${array[$index_pivot]} 1>&2
        if [ $elt -lt ${array[$index_pivot]} ];then
            echo "elt is smaller than pivot" 1>&2
            array=( ${array[@]:0:(($index_pivot + 1)) } )
        else
            echo "elt is bigger than pivot" 1>&2
            array=( ${array[@]:$index_pivot:(( ${#array[@]} - 1 ))} ) 
        fi
        findneighbours "$elt" "$state" "${array[@]}"
    fi
}



findFirstDate(){
    local file="$1"
    echo "Looking for first date in file" 1>&2
    while read line
        do 
            echo "$line" | egrep -q "^\[[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2} [0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}\]" &>/dev/null
            if [ "$?" -eq "0" ]
            then
                #echo "line=" "$line" 1>&2
                firstdate=`echo "$line" | sed -r -e "s/^\[([^\[]+)\].*/\1/"`
                echo "$firstdate"
                break
            else
                echo $? 1>&2
            fi
        done< <( cat "$file" )



}

findLastDate(){
    local file="$1"
    echo "Looking for last date in file" 1>&2
    while read line
        do 
            echo "$line" | egrep -q "^\[[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2} [0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}\]" &>/dev/null
            if [ "$?" -eq "0" ]
            then
                #echo "line=" "$line" 1>&2
                lastdate=`echo "$line" | sed -r -e "s/^\[([^\[]+)\].*/\1/"`
                echo "$lastdate"
                break
            else
                echo $? 1>&2
            fi
        done< <( tac "$file" )


}

findBestDate(){

        IFS="$old_IFS"
        local initdate="$1"
        local file="$2"
        local state="$3"
        local first_elts="$4"
        local last_elts="$5"
        local date_array=( )
        local initdate_epoch=`convertToEpoch "$initdate"`   

        if [[ $initdate_epoch -lt $first_elt ]];then
            echo `convertFromEpoch "$first_elt"`
        elif [[ $initdate_epoch -gt $last_elt ]];then
            echo `convertFromEpoch "$last_elt"` 

        else
            date_array=( `getDates "$file" "$state"` )
            echo "date_array="${date_array[@]} 1>&2
            #first_elt=${date_array[0]}
            #last_elt=${date_array[(( ${#date_array[@]} - 1 ))]}

            echo `convertFromEpoch $(findneighbours "$initdate_epoch" "$state" "${date_array[@]}")`

        fi

}


main(){
    init_date_start="$1"
    init_date_end="$2"
    filename="$3"
    echo "problem start.." 1>&2
    date_array=( "$init_date_start","$init_date_end"  )
    flag_array=( 0 0 )
    i=0
    #echo "$IFS" | cat -vte
    old_IFS="$IFS"
    #changing separator to avoid whitespace issue in date/time format
    IFS=,
    for _date in ${date_array[@]}
    do
        #IFS="$old_IFS"
        #echo "$IFS" | cat -vte
        if isDatePresent "$_date" "$filename";then
            if [ "$i" -eq 0 ];then 
                echo "Starting date exists" 1>&2
                #echo "date_start=""$_date" 1>&2
                date_start="$_date"
            else
                echo "Ending date exists" 1>&2
                #echo "date_end=""$_date" 1>&2
                date_end="$_date"
            fi

        else
            if [ "$i" -eq 0 ];then 
                echo "start date $_date not found" 1>&2
            else
                echo "end date $_date not found" 1>&2
            fi
            flag_array[$i]=1
        fi
        #IFS=,
        (( i++ ))
    done

    IFS="$old_IFS"
    if [ ${flag_array[0]} -eq 1 -o ${flag_array[1]} -eq 1 ];then

        first_elt=`convertToEpoch "$(findFirstDate "$filename")"`
        last_elt=`convertToEpoch "$(findLastDate "$filename")"`
        border_dates_array=( "$first_elt","$last_elt" )

        #echo "first_elt=" $first_elt "last_elt=" $last_elt 1>&2
        i=0
        IFS=,
        for _date in ${date_array[@]}
        do
            if [ $i -eq 0 -a ${flag_array[$i]} -eq 1 ];then
                date_start=`findBestDate "$_date" "$filename" "S" "${border_dates_array[@]}"`
            elif [ $i -eq 1 -a ${flag_array[$i]} -eq 1 ];then
                date_end=`findBestDate "$_date" "$filename" "E" "${border_dates_array[@]}"`
            fi

            (( i++ ))
        done
    fi


    sed -r -n "/^\[${date_start}\]/,/^\[${date_end}\]/p" "$filename"

}


main "$1" "$2" "$3"
```

Copy this in a file. If you don't want to see debugging info, debugging is sent to stderr so just add "2>/dev/null"

Comment: This wont display the log files which dont have time stamp.

Comment: @Amit, yes it will, have you tried?

Comment: @rMistero, it won't work because if there is no log entry at 22:30, the range won't be terminated. As OP mentioned, the start and stop times may not be in the logs. You can tweak your regex for it to work, but you'll loose resolution and never be guaranteed _in advance_ that the range will terminate at the right time.

Comment: @awk_FTW this was an example, I didn't use the timestamps provided by Amit. Again regex can be used. I agree thought it won't work if timestamp doesn't exists when provided explicitely or no timestamp regex matches. I ll improve it soon..

Comment: "As OP mentioned, the start and stop times may not be in the logs." No, read the OP again. OP says those WILL be present but intervening lines won't necessarily start with a timestamp. It doesn't even make sense to say the stop times might not be present. How could you ever tell _any_ tool where to stop if the termination marker isn't guaranteed to be there? There would be no criteria to give the tool to tell it where to stop processing.

Comment: @JoelDavis, OP: 'Please note the start time stamp or end time stamp _may not be there in the log_, but I want every line between these two time stamps.' [emphasis added]. My solution handles that situation without any problem. I think you are misunderstanding 'Some lines may not have the timestamp, but I want those lines also.' That simply means that a time-stamped record may extend over several lines, as per the example.

Comment: @rMistero, wow! I think it's totally the wrong tool for the job, but it's an impressive effort. +1 for showing that it can be done (I assume; I haven't actually checked!).

Comment: @awk_FTW: Thanks ! I know... :) But it was interesting nonetheless. I learnt the limit of arrays in bash.. you can't pass them to functions...

Comment: @rMistero, apparently, [you can pass arrays to bash functions](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4017175/918938), but it's not as easy or intuitive as other languages, and more limited. It might be a bit more convenient than the approach you took above.

Comment: @awk_FTW: cool thanks for that! I'll try. This may be a good example for the bash advanced guide I think :)

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't get the `awk` answer to work and found that sed can be used.

On https://www.unix.com/shell-programming-and-scripting/123623-pull-log-between-two-dates.html

```
sed -n '/12.Nov.2009:10:45:16/,/12.Nov.2009:10:45:16/p' infile
```

This prints all of the lines between the starting pattern and the ending pattern.  I know it doesn't exactly answer the OPs question but I thought others might find the `sed` answer useful and potentially easier than using awk.

This solution doesn't handle this:

> the start time stamp or end time stamp may not be there in the log, but I want every line between these two time stamps.

Answer (score 0):

If anybody wants to get the logs within aparticular time range (maybe you want to get the logs within 5 min) you can do like shown below. It will fetch all the logs between the time range

For dynamic time range (e.g. you don't know the time range but need logs between last 5 min)

```bash
#!/bin/bash
LOG_FILE="./modsec.txt"
SEARCH_WORD="ModSecurity: Access denied"
START_TIME=$(date -d "5 minutes ago" "+%H:%M")
END_TIME=$(date "+%H:%M")

# using sed
sed -n "/"$START_TIME"/,/"$CURRENT_TIME"/p" "$LOG_FILE" | grep -w "$SEARCH_WORD"
```

For static time range (you know the time range):

```bash
sed -n "/hh:mm/,/hh:mm/p" "$LOG_FILE" | grep -w "$SEARCH_WORD"
```

You can replace the time range based on your timestamp.