# How to assign variable in awk

Tags: shell-script, awk

I have a code like below:

```
$ awk -F'[]]|[[]' \
  '$0 ~ /^\[/ && $2 >= "2014-04-07 23:00"    { p=1 }
   $0 ~ /^\[/ && $2 >= "2014-04-08 02:00:01" { p=0 }
                                           p { print $0 }' log
```

Here I want to assign "2014-04-07" in one variable "23:00" in another variable and so on.
And get the input from their values ( using $var or something like that ).
Can someone help me to modify the above code so I can use variable instead hardcording the timestamp.

Below is the link for original question [How to extract logs between two time stamps](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/123979/how-to-extract-logs-between-two-time-stamps).

Answer (score 0):

You can either pass variables as arguments using the `-v` option:

```
awk -F'[]]|[[]' -v var1="2014-04-07 23:00" -v var2="2014-04-08 02:00:01" \
  '$0 ~ /^\[/ && $2 >= var1 { p=1 }
   $0 ~ /^\[/ && $2 >= var2 { p=0 }
   p { print $0 }' log
```

Or you can set the variables in a `BEGIN` block:

```
awk -F'[]]|[[]' \
  'BEGIN{var1="2014-04-07 23:00"; var2="2014-04-08 02:00:01"}
   $0 ~ /^\[/ && $2 >= var1 { p=1 }
   $0 ~ /^\[/ && $2 >= var2 { p=0 }
   p { print $0 }' log
```

Answer (score 0):

Of course there is another way to load your variables, through the front end as a pipe or the back end as a file or from `stdin` or a redirect. Depending on what you are doing elsewhere you can probably streamline your `awk`

Gzin

```
cat vars
2014-04-07 23:00[1
2014-04-08 02:00:01[0

cat log
[2014-04-06 23:00] Log line 1
[2014-04-07 23:00] Log line 2
[2014-04-07 23:00:01] Log line 3
[2014-04-08 02:00:01] Log line 4
```

Gzround

```
awk -F'[]]|[[]' '
   FNR==NR{v[NR]=$1; pv[NR]=$2}
   FNR!=NR{for (i=1; i<=length(v); i++) if ($2>=v[i]) p=pv[i]}
   p && $0~/^\[/{print $0}' vars log
```

Gzout

```
[2014-04-07 23:00] Log line 2
[2014-04-07 23:00:01] Log line 3
```

Perhaps not the most elegant solution, but you can compose an array, string or file to turn log filtering on and off as many times as you like and never have to fiddle with your code or add more variables.

One stop shop.

Answer (score 0):

No need to split or use that `p` variable here.

```
awk -v start='2014-04-07 23:00' -v end='2014-04-08 02:00:01' '
  '/^\[/ && $0 >= "["start && $0 < "["end' log
```