# Break up large log files

Tags: text-processing, awk

I am trying to break a large log file into smaller files based on date.

The file is of the following form, where some lines may not have a date.  Those lines should be included with the previous dated line.

```
2014-04-07T23:59:58 CheckForCallAction [ERROR] Exception caught
Undated line 1
Undated line 2
2014-04-08T00:00:03 MobileAppRequestFilter [DEBUG] Action
undated line 3
2015-04-08T00:00:03 MobileAppRequestFilter [DEBUG] ActionB
```

I found [How to extract logs between two time stamps](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/123979/how-to-extract-logs-between-two-time-stamps) which is close to what I want, except my log file does not include a "[" at the start of the date, or "]" and the end of the date.

The command from that link is:

```
awk -F'[[]|[]]' \
  '$0 ~ /^\[/ && $2 >= "2014-04-07 23:00" { p=1 }
   $0 ~ /^\[/ && $2 >= "2014-04-08 02:00" { p=0 }
   p { print $0 }' > test1.log  logwith[.log
```

I have been trying for several days to modify this, but I just can't seem to get it.

A desired enhancement would be to not have to specify a start and end date, but rather automatically name the output files by either year, or year-month.

Comment: Please see [formatting tools](http://unix.stackexchange.com/help/formatting) for help on formatting your posts.

Comment: There is an example extraction for data "without [] braces" in the answer you referenced: http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/123983/4252

Comment: The length of the date and time strings are looking very uniform to me. You can extract both with a simple `cut` command or `$1` in `awk` replaces the actual date and `$2` the actual time. In short, you don't need square brackets.  The post you linked is a common case but not necessarily the norm.

Comment: @KM, the only compact example at unix.stackexchange.com/a/123983/4252  does not include any line that do not include a date.  I need those lines.

Comment: @MelBursian  Thanks for the response.  I am not knowledgeable enough to be able to convert your guidance into a workable command. Everything I tried had $1 either a date, or for lines without a date, a string.  That made me lost as to how to proceed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `T` as the field delimiter and check for date-like strings explicitly. For example, to split by year:

```
awk -FT '($1~/^[0-9]+-[0-9]+-[0-9]+$/){d=substr($1,1,4)}{print > d".log"}' logfile
```

And by year+month:

```
awk -FT '($1~/^[0-9]+-[0-9]+-[0-9]+$/){split($1,d,"-")}{print > d[1]d[2]".log"}' logfile
```

Here, we check that the first field (defined by `T`, so the whole date on lines starting with dates, that's what `-FT` means) is a set of 3 numbers separated by `-`. If it is, to get the year, we extract the first 4 characters (`d=substr($1,1,4)`) and, to get the month, we split the 1st field on `-`, saving the resulting strings in the array `d` (`split($1,d,"-")`), and use the 1st two elements of the array (`d[1]d[2]`) for the file name.

Comment: Thank you.  This is so close to what I am looking for.  I need to be able to break up the original file either by year, or by year-month.  All variations I tired do not include the non-dated lines for some reason.  Can you tweak this?

Comment: @Mike please edit your question and explain exactly what you need. Let me know when you've done so and I'll give be it a try.

Comment: I thought I had the requirements in the question "A desired enhancement would be to not have to specify a start and end date, but rather automatically name the output files by either year, or year-month."  If that is not clear, let me know and I will try a different way.  What you provided is exactly what I wanted, only that I wanted either a yearly or monthly file, not a daily one.

Comment: @Mike indeed you did, sorry, I missed that. I'm afraid I don't have the time to do this right now, but I'll answer tomorrow. The basic nidea will probably be just taking `-` as the field delimiter.

Comment: I will appreciate that.  The variations I tried do not include the lines without dates, which is needed.  Looking forward to your resolution.

Comment: quickest fix to get logs split by year-month (**if you are using GNU `awk`**) is to change `{d=$1}` to `{d=gensub(/^(....-..).*/,"\\1",1)}`

Comment: BTW `$1~/[0-9]*-[0-9]*-[0-9]*/` should probably  be `$1~/^[0-9]+-[0-9]+-[0-9]+$/` or `$1~/^[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}$/`, otherwise it will match strings like `---` or `1--2`.

Comment: that worked perfectly.  How can I adapt it to break the original file by year?  Perhaps you would explain what {d=gensub(/^(....-..).*/,"\\1",1)} is doing?

Comment: @Mike see updated answer.

Comment: I found out that the date is terminated by a "T" and not a space.  I thought that would be a simple change for me, but I can't get it to work.  Part of my problem is that I do not understand the ~, and the +- or the $/.  I've got a lot to learn!

Comment: @terdon As noted above, my log date is actually terminated with a "T" and not s space.  While the commands for "clean" files still work fine, I prefer to use the commands you provided for logs that are not "clean".  The commands do not work for the case with the "T" at the end of the date, as they produce a file name ".log".  I tried a few variations, but was unable to figure this out.  Is this a fairly minor change?   thanks

Comment: @Mike I can't help you if you don't show examples that represent your data accurately. Do you mean the dates have an actual t or is that a tab or what?

Comment: @terdon  Sorry, I thought I was clear, but as I know all to well communications is hard.  Here is an example<br> 2014-12-19T13:19:02+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: SimpleXMLElement::__construct() [<a href='simplexmlelement.--construct'>simplexmlelement.--Text 1 without date
Text 2 without date
2014-12-19T13:19:02+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: SimpleXMLElement::__construct() [<a href='simplex
20145-01-19T13:19:02+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: SimpleXMLElement::__construct() [<a href='sim

Comment: I do not know how to format the linefeed, but I hope you understand what the format is.  Let me know how/if you want an attachment.

Comment: @Mike please take the [tour] to understand how this site works and how it differs from traditional forums. All the relevant information needs to be in your question. That way, the next reader will understand both the question and the relevance of the answer. Also, comments don't support [formatting tools](http://unix.stackexchange.com/help/formatting) which is another reason why including everything in the question makes sense.

Comment: @Mike I have edited your question so that it shows a correct representation of your data (I think) and have updated the answer as well. If your input is actually different from what you show, please just accept this answer and post a new question.

Comment: @terdon Sorry for the delay, but I just got a chance to test this out, and it worked perfectly.  Broke a 7+G file into 15 monthly files.  Using wc -l I was able to confirm that all the lines are there.  I would like to understand this fully so what is the ~ used for after the $1, what is the function of the +- after each of the [0-9} in the regular expression, and what is the +$ before the final /?  Also, I do not understand why the lines with no dates are included?  Thanks again.