# grep data between two timestamps

Tags: linux, bash, grep

I am so beginner with linux .

```
    Oct 07  11:00:33 some text
    Oct 07  12:00:33 some text
    Oct 08  14:00:33 some text
    Oct 08  21:00:33 some text
    Oct 09  21:00:33 some text
```

I would like to grep logs between **2015-07-08 12:00:33** to **2015-07-10 21:00:31**

I think I can do that with these codes that I've got from [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/635105/grep-logs-between-two-timestamps) ,

```
sudo awk -v start='2015-07-08 12:00:33' -v end='2015-07-10 21:00:31' '
 BEGIN{ gsub(/[:-]/," ", start); gsub(/[:-]/," ", end) }
      { dt=$1" "$2; gsub(/[:-]/," ", dt) }
 mktime(dt)>=mktime(start) && mktime(dt)<=mktime(end)' a.txt
```

I've tested it and it works perfectly when log date time format is `2015-10-09 21:00:33`

but my log date time format is `Oct 09  21:00:33`

so I don't know How to convert it to `2015-10-09 21:00:33`

Comment: There's a lesson: whatever writes to your logs, configure it to use a format like `2015-10-29 21:00:33`, because *timestamps in such format can be parsed, sorted or compared relatively easily*. It doesn't have to be this exact format. The point is some formats are better than others when it comes to parsing, sorting or comparing; use this fact. I know this comment won't solve your current problem, but it may help avoid future ones.

Comment: I always prefer storing time in epoch seconds for this reason. Whatever you want you just convert to epoch second. Then back. At that the check you want is just a comparison of two integers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your logged timestamps is not easily parseable, so you will need to convert it to some parseable and also acceptable format to the [mktime() function](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Time-Functions.html) which is *`YYYY MM DD HH MM SS`* and since you having missing YYYY part so for that we added a dummy year as "2022" in the following code.

There is also a user-defined month2num() function which it converts the Months name into thier corresponding month-number.

```
gawk -v year='2022'  -v start='2022 10 07 12 00 33' -v end='2022 10 08 21 00 31' '
function month2num(mon ){
     return sprintf("%02d", (index("JanFebMarAprMayJunJulAugSepOctNovDec", mon)+2)/3)
 }

{ dt=year" "month2num($1)" "$2" "$3; gsub(/[:-]/," ", dt) }

mktime(dt)>=mktime(start) && mktime(dt)<=mktime(end)' infile
```

Output:

```
    Oct 07  12:00:33 some text
    Oct 08  14:00:33 some text
```